# java declaring a generic array

Tags: java, arrays, generics

First of all I am new to Java, very little experience.

In a class I have the following attribute

```
private List<Arc> arcs[]; // an array of a List of type Arc
```

In the constructor of the class i am trying to initialize it:

```
 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 arcs = new List[500];
```

But it wont compile. I have been trying to figure out how to initialize this type of array, I seen the use of Array.newinstance which i dont understand.

thanks for your help

Solution:

arcs = new List[500];

Comment: Hmmm, your variable is kind of badly named... The List of Arcs should be called arcs, you have an array of lists, is that what you really intended? otherwise I'd call it arcLists (given I have no way of tying it to the real world and calling it "arcDealership" or something more usage based)

Comment: @JeffWatkins yes what i want is an array of lists. How do i declare this

Comment: Please edit your question as it was before and accept the answer. Currentlly your problem is the solution.

Comment: Generics and arrays really don't mix very well.  Try to avoid them in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this :

```
arcs = new List[500];
```

but not "Lista".

I'm afraid your problem here is just a typo...

Comment: The first statement would not compile.

Comment: @assylias You're right... oops...

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be mixing things here.

If what you need is a one dimension array, you can use a List or an array, but not both:

```
    List<Arc> list = new ArrayList<Arc>();
    list.add(new Arc());

    Arc[] array = new array[1];
    array[0] = new Arc();
```

Unless you really do need a List of arrays (a 2D structure) but it does not seem to be the case.

**EDIT**

Based on you comment, you want an array of lists, which would look like:

```
List<Arc>[] listOfArrays = new List[500]; //you can't easily mix arrays and generics
List<Arc> list = new ArrayList<Arc>();
list.add(new Arc());
listOfArrays[0] = list;
```

ps: you could also use a list of lists:

```
List<List<Arc>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<List<Arc>>();
List<Arc> list = new ArrayList<Arc>();
list.add(new Arc());
listOfLists.add(list);
```

Comment: I need that each "box", each position of the array to have a list.

Comment: Yeah that was suggested to me. Silly me. When still learning. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, to avoid warnings you'd use a list of lists

```
List< List<Arc>> arcLists = new ArrayList< List< Arc >>();
```

Of course, in Java 7, that would probably look a bit cleaner with type inference.

If you're hell-bent on arrays, use

```
arcs = (ArrayList<Arc>[]) new ArrayList[500];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not do what you want because, arrays contain at runtime infomation about its component type. The generics do not. So to create a array you must know the type, this mean you can not use generics in this case.

That is why code `List<Arcs>[] arcs` is valid  and `new ArrayList<Arcs>[500]` is not.

Same error you will get when you will try to do something like this (T is generic)

```
T[] genericArray = new T[];
```

The error complier fail with is: `Cannot create a generic array`

To avoit it you can create something like this:

`List<Arcs>[] arcs = new ArrayList[500];`

But thsi is not type safe, to have a type save solution you should use below code:

`List<List<Arcs>> lista = new ArrayList<List<Arcs>>();`